# Group nodes by connections

Tags: algorithm, d3.js, graph, social-networking, connected-components

I would like to know if there is a proper algorithm to group nodes for the following problem:

Input:  Relational disconnected graph, with following data structure:

```
per_id com_id

 1        1
 2        1
 2        2
 3        2
 3        3
 4        3
 5        7
 5        8
 6        7
```

Output: Cluster all persons which have a directed/undirected relation, taken as reference the company attribute in a force layout graph (D3.js). The output of the example above would be to draw a circle/bubble force layout graph with 2 bubbles containing the following persons:

Group 1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}

Group 2 = {5, 6}

[image: Force Layout Graph example]

Comment: Can you specify your problem in general? One example is not a replacement for a specification of the task. We need to know what the correct output is, as a function of the input. Thanks.

Comment: I update my problem, maybe it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you simply looking for the `GROUP_BY com_id` SQL operarion?

Group all persons in each company?

How would your expected result differ from this classic relational operation?